# Windows10 で「貼り付け」のレジストリキーパスを知りたい

Tags: windows

やりたいこと
Windows10でファイル切り取り後右クリックした際に表示されるコンテキストメニューで、貼付けを一番上に表示したい

Q
Windows10 で「貼り付け」のレジストリキーはどこにありますか？

Comment: 目的の操作は出来ないかもしれませんが、こんな記事が何か参考になるかも。[Windows 10 でコンテキストメニューを編集する方法](https://polygonote.com/2022_1109_18874/), [How to edit the Windows 10 context menu](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-edit-the-windows-10-context-menu), [7 of the Best Context Menu Editors for Windows](https://www.maketecheasier.com/best-context-menu-editors/)

Comment: 「 7 of the Best Context Menu Editors for Windows 」が大変参考になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問はレジストリキーで管理されていると決め付けられていますが、そもそもレジストリキーでは管理されていません。